# Openssl decryption failed

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I have the following code:

```
/* CRYPTING PARAMETERS */
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$kpart1 = "IsdI685cUY";
$ipart1 = "RkEgfA";
$statement = "SELECT `crypt_key`, `iv` FROM `tab_sec`;";
$result = $conn->query($statement);
$row1 = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$kpart2 = $row1["crypt_key"];
$ipart2 = $row1["iv"];
$key = $kpart1 . $kpart2;
$iv = $ipart1 . $ipart2;

$statement = "SELECT * FROM `tab_employees` WHERE `id` = '$q';";
$sth = $conn->query($statement);
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$number = openssl_decrypt($row["number"], $method, $key, $options=0, $iv);
```

I decrypt the encrypted data from the SQL database. If I decrypt data the operation returns FALSE. The `$key` and `$iv` paramethers are correct. I get right values. I used the same paramethers also if I encrypted the data and stored them in SQL, so I don't understand where the problem could be.

Comment: Well for us to help you will have to show how you encrypt the data

Comment: And provide the very data samples.

Comment: PS: This does not seem very secure! Unless this data is encrypted `at rest` using another key, then if I steal you DB I have all I need to decrypt everything. And that does not even take into account the ability for anyone with read access to your DB doing that as well

Comment: So I would say you are wasting your time and lots of CPU Cycles and achieving no security at all

Comment: @RiggsFolly I will be very gratefull if you tell me, how to encrypt and decrypt securely. I'm the beginner in encryption. I saw some examples but I don't understand them. I saw examples with openssl_cipher_iv_length and openssl_random_pseudo_bytes but I also can't decrypt the data. I think because of random bytes.

Comment: _I'm the beginner in encryption_ Sorry to say this but that is your biggest danger. Get your encryption strategy validated by an expert before even beginning to code anything

Comment: But Rule 1: Your key must be kept securely, and separate from your data